# Medalha Conversador?

Tags: suporte, tags, tag-específica

Acredito que se uma empresa olhar o meu perfil e ver essa medalha poderá considerar isso uma coisa ruim.

Tem como eu abdicar dessa medalha? Ou há como mudarem o nome da medalha para outra coisa que não possa ser considerada pejorativa? Tipo "Comunicativo" ? Ou "Sociável" ?

Nem frequento tanto assim os chats, ganhei essa medalha por enviar dez mensagens e uma delas ter recebido uma estrelinha de alguém, informando que um dos meus comentários era útil para a transcrição.

Comment: Creio que vá do contexto da frase, se disse-se "tagarela" então teria sentido pensar assim, creio que no "contexto" não seja.

Comment: Pô Guilherme, muda lá pra "Sociável" ^_^

Comment: Não era necessário sinalizar, o meta está aqui para resolver, moderadores não podem intervir neste tipo de coisa, é algo mais de adm do site mesmo. Os moderadores são eleitos, mas não são funcionários da SO.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não são só os admins... Qualquer pessoa pode ajudar a traduzir o site no nosso [projeto no Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/)

Comment: @Gabe sim, tem razão, mas antes temos que ter um consenso da comunidade. Alguma observação referente ao assunto?

Comment: @Math Não. Eu gosto das sugestões, mas não tenho nada contra o nome atual.

Comment: @Gabe é verdade, vou começar a referenciar o link, eu mesmo preciso passar a usar este, criei a conta e nada até agora, logo irei ver ;)

Comment: Eu não tenho opinião formada ainda porque eu não vejo problemas no nome, mas se alguém vê, é de se pensar. Você pode trocar bunda por bumbum, mas continuará sendo um par de glúteos. Se a pessoa que ver a medalha não quiser saber o significado não deve ser a única coisa que ela não analisa direito e aí este é o menor dos problemas. Se a pessoa que vai analisar acha que conversar é algo ruim, acho que há outro problema nessa seleção e possivelmente na vaga. É uma medalha, não um auto de infração. Mas é só minha visão de acordo com meu *background*.

Comment: Na verdade o problema é a medalha existir porque as pessoas estrelam coisas inúteis quando o recurso foi feito para estrelar só coisa útil, ou seja a medalha deveria ser para mostrar que a pessoa é capaz de fazer algo positivo e não algo bobo.

Comment: @bigown também não vejo problema.